# Bitmap decode issues with Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, bitmapfactory

I'm having problems when decoding imagens in Lollipop devices.

The picture below shows a "testing app", that decodes 4 png files.

Left = kitkat 4.4.4, Right = lollypop (5.0.1)

Both in same device type: MOTO G 2nd Generation.

[image]

**Relevant Code**:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = true;
options.inScaled = true;
options.inDensity = 160;
options.inTargetDensity = 320;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAsBytes), null, options);
```

**Screen Metrics:**

```
Density......: 2
ScaledDensity: 2
DensityDPI...: 320
Size.........: 720x1184
```

I've found any explanation in the web.

Anyone can point me why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

As it's happening only with lollipop + TargetDensity = 320 + Density = 160, I did the following workaround:

```
if ((android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) && (options.inTargetDensity == 320) && (options.inDensity = 160))
{
    options.inDensity = options.inTargetDensity;
}
```

But I really appreciate some tips to figer it out what's going on...

Comment: Hi Christian. Did u found a Solution in the Meantime. I have exactly the same Problem?    chris @ guruk.com

Comment: Just a workaround. Check question's edit... cheers.

Comment: thanks... its very strange. It seems its not just moto g . instead several motorola devices. Im wondering why nobody else wrote about.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering the same... I've seen nobody talking about it.

Comment: Small improvements:
options.inDensity = options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
No need to do additional check points. I tested it on 4.4.2, 5.0.1 and even 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bellow the Solution in my case was (to add setDensity and to use the new BitmapDrawable that looks on Density). Hope it also helps u too. (btw. this 2 lines, did cost me 3 Days :)

```
 final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(44, 65, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

 /*NEW -> */ output.setDensity(320);

 final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
 final int color = Color.RED;
 final Paint paint = new Paint();

 // BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(output);
 /*Change into*/
 BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),output);
```

Comment: Will this break if running in "older" devices? Like Android 2.3 with lowres screens?